# Check if file exists in artifactory without downloading

Tags: artifactory

I need to check if a file exists. My approach until now was doing it via Artifactory REST API

```
url = https://artifactory.io/path_to_file/file.jar
headers = {'X-JFrog-Art-Api': 'api_key'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
assert(200 == response.status_code)
assert(response.text != "")
```

but there's a file that it too big and it's taking too long to get the response.

Is there another way to check if this file exists?

Comment: You could call `requests.head` instead of `requests.get`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As commented by [Roland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5629418/roland-weber), I've just call `requests.head` and it was enough

Answer (score 5):

You could check the status code returned when getting the file info, not the file itself.

See the [documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-FileInfo) of this REST API.

For example:

`url = https://artifactory.io/api/storage/path_to_file/file.jar`

```
headers = {'X-JFrog-Art-Api': 'api_key'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
assert(200 == response.status_code)
assert(response.text != "")
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use one of the [Search APIs](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-SEARCHES) or (and that is what I recommend) use the [JFrog CLI search](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-SearchingFiles) commands